# How to return Mobile Connect phone priority using API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, mobileconnect

We have an automated process of importing updated (changed) phone numbers. We add them through the import process and assign priority "1". We want to ensure that import is successful through validation process. Unfortunately, I have not found an appropriate API request to return MobileConnect phone priority. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think there is an API route that could do this efficiently, if at all. Does this have to be an API route you're looking for? Could you not use an SQL Query in Automation Studio?

Comment: @Macca it's not critical limitation to use API for that. As I understand you suggest using Data Views for validation but would it be possible to validate based on contactKey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API Route that I'm aware of that lets you get this data out in an efficient manner.

The _MobileAddress data view allows you to pull all address records in MobileConnect irrespective of their priority, though. By default, the data view doesn't contain the SubscriberKey, but it does contain any MobileConnect Demographic fields you've created. The trick is to ensure you [create a MobileConnect Demographic Field](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_create_an_attribute.htm&type=5) to hold your SubscriberKeys for each contact and include this field in your import defintion each time you perform your import of new/updated contacts. You can then include it in the data you retrieve from _MobileAddress.

Here's an example of querying the Data View pulling all address records along with their SubscriberKey imported into a custom demographic field called "UUID".

```
SELECT
    UUID AS SubscriberKey,
    _ContactID AS ContactID,
    _MobileNumber AS MobileNumber,
    _Status AS Status,
    _Priority AS Priority
FROM 
    _MobileAddress WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Interesting solution. It's very likely that I would decide to go this way.